# internationalisation in django

Tags: django, django-admin

I am doing internationalisation in django admin.I am able to convert  all my text to the specific langauge.But i m not able to change the 'app' name

suppose

django-admin.py startapp test

this will create a app called test inside my project.Inside this app 'test' i can create many classes in my model.py file.But when i register my app 'test' in settings.py file.I am convert all the text in the locale of my browser but my app heading 'test' is not getting  changed.How to change that any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a well known problem in django and there is a [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1668) since 2006

a workaround for this would be to place all the appnames (with upper und lower-case) manually in your *.po-file.

to ensure django-admin will catch this, Replaced this:

```
    <caption> 
       <a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="section"> 
            {% blocktrans with app.name as name %}{{ name }}{% endblocktrans %} 
        </a> 
   </caption>
```

with this:

```
  <caption>
     <a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="section">{% trans app.name %}</a>
  </caption>
```

maybe [this](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1882/) snippet would help too?

Answer (score 0):

Defining an i18n-ized name, or any other custom app name is not natively possible.

Check out:

- [Can you give a Django app a verbose name for use throughout the admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612372/can-you-give-a-django-app-a-verbose-name-for-use-throughout-the-admin)
- http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3591

As mentioned in the question and ticket, there are several workarounds.