# How to display multi-word app names properly (i.e. with spaces) in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm struggling to find a way to get multi-word app names to display properly in Django admin.

I've tried CamelCasing, hyphens and underscores, but in each case the app name just displays in admin exactly as it's named in the project. I've searched around for the answer but oddly can't seem to find one.

I'm sure I must be missing something obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, afik, django doesn't really support the notion of "verbose names" for apps. The admin just does `app_name.title()`. So to get want you want, some more trickery is needed. Haven't tried (never needed this) but [this solution](http://snipt.net/chrisdpratt/overriding-app_label-in-django-admin/) may just work.

Comment: Aha, thanks, I didn't think of anything as simple as a template filter. That looks like it would work nicely, although it would obviously be much neater if Django added something like verbose_name for apps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is super old but it was the first one I came across when searching for this. There is a way to use verbose_name as you can find in the answer here:

[Can you give a django app a verbose name for use through the admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612372/can-you-give-a-django-app-a-verbose-name-for-use-throughout-the-admin/6312798)