# Django admin menu labeling

Tags: django, django-cms

Is there a way to change the application label in the admin menu ? I just can't find how.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3164163/455833

Answer (score 0):

Check [django-app-name-translation-in-admin](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-app-name-translation-in-admin/tree/next). It overrides few django admin templates to allow translating application names. While not perfect way, it could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the application label for a particular model using the `app_label` attribute in a `Meta` class:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    ... fields ...

    class Meta:
        app_label = "Your App Label Goes Here"
```

This only applies for this particular model, so if you want to change the app label for all models in an app, you will have to add this for each model.