# Django changing app name of Photologue

Tags: python, django, django-models, photologue

i have installed photologue - A customizable plug-in photo management application for the Django web framework [here](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) into my project without problem...

now i want to change app name in admin page which is **photologue**. for this i have used ugettext_lazy but i got an error when i define this to all Meta:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Meta:
    app_label = _('newappname')
```

Error:

```
ValueError at /admin/

Cannot create form field for 'effect' yet, because its related model 
'PhotoEffect' has not been loaded yet
```

Is there any easy way for changing app name, i have looked a lot but didnt find...

Answer (score 2):

Django does not support app renaming in the admin right now, but [ticket #3591](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3591) was raised to add that functionality, so hopefully it will be added.

There are several ways of acomplishing that. The simplest and preferred would be changing the main admin template and using whatever name you want as the app name there.

Other solutions:

- [How to change the name of a Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/django-how-to-change-the-name-of-an-app)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312798/342473
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1882/

Comment: @thanks for replying... how can i install this ticket, i have never installed any ticket before... and changing template i didnt find my app name in change_list.html ...

Comment: Look for lines like `{% blocktrans with name=app.name %}{{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}`. E.g the admin index template: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html#L21

Comment: this method is not fit to me bacause of using grappelli ui in django... can u help me about installing this ticket..