# verbose name app in django admin interface

Tags: django, admin, verbose

In the Django administration Interface, we have our models grouped by app. Well, I known how to customize the model name:

```
class MyModel (models.Model):
  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'My Model'
    verbose_name_plural = 'My Models'
```

But I couldn't customize the app name. Is there any verbose_name for the apps ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you give a Django app a verbose name for use throughout the admin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612372/can-you-give-a-django-app-a-verbose-name-for-use-throughout-the-admin)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since django 1.7 app_label does not work. You have to follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#for-application-authors instructions.
That is:

1. Create `apps.py` in your app's directory
2. Write verbose name :

   ```
   # myapp/apps.py

   from django.apps import AppConfig

   class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
       name = 'myapp'
       verbose_name = "Rock ’n’ roll"
   ```
3. In the project's settings change `INSTALLED_APPS` :

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig',
       # ...
   ]
   ```

   **Or**, you can leave `myapp.apps`in `INSTALLED_APPS` and make your application load this AppConfig subclass by default as follows:

   ```
   # myapp/__init__.py

   default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
   ```

alles :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Meta class inside your model and defining the app_label there works, but most likely you will have to do that for each model in your module.

Another approach is to actually use `i18n`. In your po file, if you define a **msgid** with your **app_label** you should be good.

In your app, add/edit po file *app_label > locale > ru > django.po*

```
#set app label string 
msgid <app_label>
msgstr "Ваше приложение этикетке"
```

You can read more about the internationalization [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#term-translation-string) and about translation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/).

Answer (score -1):

Add `app_label` attr to your `MyModel` inner `META` class

```
class MyModel (models.Model):
  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'My Model'
    verbose_name_plural = 'My Models'
    app_label = 'wow_app_name'
```

Comment: @andi thanks for mentioning that, I've updated the `app_label`