# Django. Meta app label in russian language.

Tags: python, django, localization, django-admin

Have problem same as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694078/verbose-name-app-in-django-admin-interface) question, but I want to label my application in russian language. Is there any workaround for this?

When I'm just changing app_label to russian title - it tries to create table in russian in code `self.db_table = "%s_%s" % (self.app_label, self.module_name)`

Comment: if you are using internationalization, you can use `ugettext_lazy("%s_%s"%(self.app_label, self.module_name))`

Comment: @karthikr, I quoted code from django 1.5 core.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by including `db_table` manually this behavior can be corrected:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'table_name'
    app_label = 'app name in russian'
```

You may check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/) for further info.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, app_label has a lot of dependencies in core. That helped for db_table, but now I have error `Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': u'\u0410\u0434\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043c\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043d\u043e\u0432'}' not found.`.. I think core hacking is not the solution. But thanks!

Comment: Just a question, what do you want to label your application in russian? For some output? This sure have a solution!

Comment: Yes, for some output. I think, changing template will help, but it is not so fast. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Meta class inside your model and defining the app_label there works, but most likely you will have to do that for each model in your module.

Another approach is to actually use `i18n`. In your po file, if you define a **msgid** with your **app_label** you should be good.

In your app, add/edit po file *app_label > locale > ru > django.po*

```
#set app label string 
msgid <app_label>
msgstr "Ваше приложение этикетке"
```

You can read more about the internationalization [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#term-translation-string) and about translation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/).