# How to modify the app name in Django admin's urls?

Tags: django, url, admin

In a Django app the urls of the admin contains the app name, ex:

```
http://my.domain.com/admin/myapp/mymodel
```

How can I replace `myapp` by another string (without modifying the actual app name of course)?

**EDIT**

My db already exists, so I can't use `app_label` in my models' `META`.
I just want to modify the app name displayed in the admin urls and the admin pages.

Comment: There seems to be only answers for the models, but what about the admin login page `http://my.domain.com/admin/myapp/`? Isn't there a global way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set `app_label` on each model of your app by defining an abstract model, like it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5819110/771848). If you have an existing database, as a workaround, you can override `db_table` on each model as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628988/771848).

Another option is to use awesome [django-admin-tools](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/) module, that is very powerful at customizing your admin site. You can define your own `DashboardModule` and customize links as you want.

Also see:

- [Can you give a Django app a verbose name for use throughout the admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612372/can-you-give-a-django-app-a-verbose-name-for-use-throughout-the-admin/615760#615760)

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is only for models. This does not change the admin login page `http://my.domain.com/admin/myapp/` for instance. Isn't there a global way to do that? Using `django-admin-tools` is not an option.

Comment: `app_label` is used by the model managers, so since my DB already exists, I can't modify it.

Comment: Agreed, what about overriding admin templates - is that an option for you?

Comment: That's an option, but what about the urls?