# How to change "app name" in Django admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-apps

I created `'frontend'` application using `./manage.py startproject frontend`.

But for some reason I just want to change the app name in the Django admin to display `'Your Home Page'` instead of `'frontend'`.

How to do that?

Update:
Here is the little more detail:

```py
# "settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'frontend',
)
```

And:

```py
# "frontend/models.py"

class Newpage(models.Model):
    # field here

class Oldpage(models.Model):
    #field here
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you give a Django app a verbose name for use throughout the admin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612372/can-you-give-a-django-app-a-verbose-name-for-use-throughout-the-admin)

Answer (score 59):

Yes, you can do it simply

in your *apps.py* file from your app folder change the verbose_name attribute from your config class. For example:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class FrontendConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'frontend'
    verbose_name = "Your Home Page"
```

I test it and works in Django 1.10

**UPDATE:**

In Django 3+ you should add this in your `__init__.py` file (from your app)

```
default_app_config = 'frontend.apps.FrontendConfig'
```

Comment: I tested it, it works fine in Django 1.11.15 (Python 2.7.15) too. Thanks.

Comment: @Jekson try to add this on your __init__.py from frontend app `default_app_config = 'frontend'`

Comment: @FACode it should be `default_app_config = "frontend.apps.FrontendConfig"` or something like that

Comment: @DataGreed yes, you're right in the newer versions of django you should add this in your __init__.py

Answer (score 18):

In stars/app.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class RequestsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'stars'
    verbose_name = "Star of India"
```

in  stars/**init**.py

```
default_app_config = 'stars.apps.RequestsConfig'
```

To access the app name in custom menu methods you can try to get that from

```
model._meta.app_config.verbose_name
```

Check the Django Doc for reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#for-application-users

Answer (score 8):

I am late but just to add an additional step to the solution explained by @[FACode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5911514/facode).
From the offical [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#for-application-users):

## In frontend/apps.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class FrontendConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'frontend'
    verbose_name = "Your Home Page"
```

## In app/settings.py

```py
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'frontend.apps.FrontendConfig',
        # ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 8):

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class FrontendConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'frontend'
    verbose_name = "Your Home Page"
```

__ init__.py

```
default_app_config = 'frontend.apps.FrontendConfig'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/

Comment: please provide some explanation for your content, it's unclear that this is an answer or a new question.

Comment: This is an answer for question, a writed how to change name of app, and gived link for docs.

Answer (score 4):

1.Try to add app_label to your model that will be registered in Admin.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
        pass
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'My APP name'
```

**UPDATE:**
2. Steps to rename app(folders):

- Rename the folder which is in your project root
- Change any references to your app in their dependencies, i.e. the app's views, the urls.py  and settings.py files.
- Edit the database table django_content_type with the following command: UPDATE django_content_type SET app_label='' WHERE app_label=''
- Also if you have models, you will have to rename the model tables. For postgres use ALTER TABLE _modelName RENAME TO _modelName.
  For renaming models, you'll need to change django_content_type.name
  Note: If your models.py 's Meta Class has app_name listed, make sure to rename that too.

Comment: @ZenMaster Could you share you models.py?

Comment: i need to change the `frontend` not the model

Answer (score 4):

For example, if app name is `store`, then add [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) with `my store` to `store/apps.py` as shown below:

```py
# "store/apps.py"

from django.apps import AppConfig

class StoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'store'
    verbose_name = "my store" # Here
```

Then, add the code below to **"store/**init**.py"**:

```py
# "store/__init__.py"

default_app_config = 'store.apps.StoreConfig'
```

Now, the app name `store` is changed to `my store` as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## In apps.py

```
 from django.apps import AppConfig
 class AccountConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app name'
    verbose_name = "new app name"
```

Comment: Is there any information in this answer that isn't already covered by the other answers?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to change how the appname is listed within the Django Admin?  This wasn't possible before Django 1.7, but now you can do it like this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#for-application-users

Answer (score 1):

In Django 2 we can use verbose_name in apps.py but we have to specify the CLass Config in **init**.py

[See related doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#for-application-authors)

Answer (score 0):

in django 3.0+ you just need to change the folder name and inside the apps.py change the "name" inside the "(*appname*)Config" class to the new name.