# How to change app a model is displayed under in Django Admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I know I can change the display title for a model in Django Admin using

```
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Custom Model Name Here'
```

However, is there a way to display which app heading a model is displayed under?

For example, if I create a custom user model `Users` in a new app also called `users` then the default user model goes from `Authentication and Authorization > Users` to `Users > Users`.

I would like to retain it under the original heading `Authentication and Authorization > Users`.

[image]

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972625/how-to-change-app-name-in-django-admin) answer however it only changes the verbose name of the app associated with the model. I want to show the model in a different group on the admin panel. You can see the issue that approach takes here:

[image]

Comment: I think it was wrong closed, the duplicated one is not asking the same.

Comment: See this is not the same question. I will edit to clarify the difference.

Comment: Okay, I had a response for you. I will post it when after resolving it.

Comment: I have reworded the question again here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125725/how-to-reassign-a-model-to-a-different-app-for-display-only-purposes-in-django-a