# django, how change table prefix globally

Tags: django, django-models

How can I change the DB table prefix in Django?
I only found a "per table" solution withe the meta option, but I want to define it for all tables.

Comment: There is not currently any way to do this. See for example [Django ticket 891](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/891).

Comment: As an addendum to my earlier comment, you might want to look at [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-db-prefix/1.0.5).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612372/can-you-give-a-django-app-a-verbose-name-for-use-throughout-the-admin